# Como cambio el valor de una variable que se envió como parámetro a una función?

Tags: java, mysql, oracle

Estoy trabajando en Java pero no entiendo como hacer para que el parámetro que le pase a la función se cambie en mi variable original.
Esta es la parte del codigo

```
 public boolean getContraseña(String nombre_usuario, String guardarResultado){
    boolean exitoEjecucionConsulta;        
    super.conectar();
    try{
        super.sql = "SELECT clave_usuario FROM usuario WHERE nombre_usuario = '"+nombre_usuario+"'";    
        super.st = super.conn.createStatement();
        super.rst = super.st.executeQuery(super.sql);
        while(super.rst.next()){          
            guardarResultado = this.rst.getString(1);
        }           
        exitoEjecucionConsulta = true;
    }catch(SQLException e){
        exitoEjecucionConsulta = false;
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Parece que algo ha salido mal: \""+e.getMessage()+"\"","Error de conexion",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }finally{
        super.desconectar();
    }        
    return exitoEjecucionConsulta;
}
```

Al ejecutar eso se supone que la variable guardarResultado debe almacenar lo que reciba de la consulta, pero al salir de la función la variable original sigue con el contenido que tenia antes te llamar a la función.
¿Como logro que mi función me cambie el contenido a la variable que se envió como parámetro?

Answer (score 0):

En java, todos los tipos primitivos son pasados por valor y no por referencia.  Para lograr lo que deseas mira este ejemplo:

```
AtomicReference<Object> ref = new AtomicReference<Object>("Hello");
mutate(ref);
System.out.println(ref.get()); //Goodbye!

private void mutate(AtomicReference<Object> ref) { ref.set("Goodbye"); }
```

Este ejemplo imprime "Goodbye" y no "Hello".  El valor de la variable cambia, que es lo que tu quieres.

Referencia: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068760/can-i-pass-parameters-by-reference-in-java

Comment: Dicho de otro modo: un método puede mutar el parámetro recibido, pero no sustituirlo por otro.